# Custom JSON deserializer using Gson

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson

I have a problem with parsing a JSON response using Gson.

JSON string:

```
response: [
  2, {
    owner_id: 23972237,
    album_id: 25487692,
    title: 'album not new'
  }, {
    owner_id: 23972237,
    album_id: 25486631,
    title: 'фыв'
  }
]
```

I have these 2 classes:

```
public class VkAudioAlbumsResponse {
    public ArrayList<VkAudioAlbum> response;
    public VkError error;
}

public class VkAudioAlbum {
    public int owner_id;
    public int album_id;
    public String title;
}
```

But I have an Exception when parse this using Gson.
I know this is because response array first element is not an object, but  integer.

So the question is, can I solve it somehow?

Comment: Your so called "JSON string" is not a valid JSON string.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You have to write a [**custom deserializer**](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Writing-a-Deserializer). I'd do something like this:

First you need to include a new class, further than the 2 you already have:

```
public class Response {
    public VkAudioAlbumsResponse response;
}
```

And then you need a custom deserializer, something similar to this:

```
private class VkAudioAlbumsResponseDeserializer 
    implements JsonDeserializer<VkAudioAlbumsResponse> {

  @Override
  public VkAudioAlbumsResponse deserialize(JsonElement json, Type type,
        JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

    JsonArray jArray = (JsonArray) json;

    int firstInteger = jArray.get(0); //ignore the 1st int

    VkAudioAlbumsResponse vkAudioAlbumsResponse = new VkAudioAlbumsResponse();

    for (int i=1; i<jArray.size(); i++) {
      JsonObject jObject = (JsonObject) jArray.get(i);
      //assuming you have the suitable constructor...
      VkAudioAlbum album = new VkAudioAlbum(jObject.get("owner_id").getAsInt(), 
                                            jObject.get("album_id").getAsInt(), 
                                            jObject.get("title").getAsString());
      vkAudioAlbumsResponse.getResponse().add(album);
    }

    return vkAudioAlbumsResponse;
  }  
}
```

Then you have to deserialize your JSON like:

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(VkAudioAlbumsResponse.class, new VkAudioAlbumsResponseDeserializer());
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
Response response = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Response.class);
```

With this approach, when Gson tries to deserialize the JSON into `Response` class, it finds that there is an attribute `response` in that class that matches the name in the JSON response, so it continues parsing.

Then it realises that this attribute is of type `VkAudioAlbumsResponse`, so it uses the custom deserializer you have created to parse it, which process the remaining portion of the JSON response and returns an object of `VkAudioAlbumsResponse`.

*Note: The code into the deserializer is quite straightforward, so I guess you'll have no problem to understand it... For further info see [**Gson API Javadoc**](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.2.3/docs/javadocs/overview-summary.html)*

Comment: Great answer, even if I prefer to create a private method instead of creating a new class ;)

Comment: @MattiaRuggiero I much prefer a separate class with that specific responsibility - having lots of small classes is always good imo, as long as you organise them clearly...