# Gson "2014-06-12T11:05:37.425Z" to date in Android

Tags: android, gson

i need to convert a String with this format

```
2014-06-12T11:05:37.425Z
```

To a date for parse with this class:

```
package com.virteu.gg.domain;

import java.util.Date;

/**
 * Created by colymore on 13/6/14.
 */
public class Status {

  private String id;
  private State[] states;

  public Status() {
  }

  public Status(String id, State[] states) {
    this.id = id;
    this.states = states;
  }

  public State[] getStates() {
    return states;
  }

  public void setStates(State[] states) {
    this.states = states;
  }

  public String getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  class State {
    private Date date;
    private String state;

    State(Date date, String state) {
      this.date = date;
      this.state = state;
    }
  }
}
```

Im trying with this:

```
 Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz")
        .create();
        Status[] status = gson.fromJson(value.toString(), new TypeToken<Status[]>() {}.getType());
```

But give me this error;

```
 06-13 13:30:34.959  28113-28113/? E/Report ::﹕ com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: 2014-06-12T11:05:37.425Z--------- Stack trace ---------
    com.google.gson.DefaultDateTypeAdapter.deserializeToDate(DefaultDateTypeAdapter.java:107)    com.google.gson.DefaultDateTypeAdapter.deserialize(DefaultDateTypeAdapter.java:82)    com.google.gson.DefaultDateTypeAdapter.deserialize(DefaultDateTypeAdapter.java:35)    com.google.gson.TreeTypeAdapter.read(TreeTypeAdapter.java:58)    com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:93)    com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172)    com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40)    com.google.gson.internal.bind.ArrayTypeAdapter.read(ArrayTypeAdapter.java:72)    com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:93)    com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172)    com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40)    com.google.gson.internal.bind.ArrayTypeAdapter.read(ArrayTypeAdapter.java:72)    com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:803)    com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:768)    com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:717)    com.virteu.gg.activities.LoginActivity$3.success(LoginActivity.java:115)    com.virteu.gg.services.api.ApiCallBase.apiSuccess(ApiCallBase.java:39)    com.virteu.gg.services.api.GetStatusApiCall$1.onSuccess(Ge
```

How can i do it this..?I dont know so much about gson library..

Comment: Use custom deserializer

[Here's an example][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16590377/custom-json-deserializer-using-gson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your date string pattern is wrong.
Try to use `setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")`