# Android: Reading JSON data into a class with ArrayList

Tags: java, android, json, azure, gson

I'm using the Azure SDK which includes GSON to store query results from Microsoft Azure into a class.  I've been following the instructions from this example: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2013/06/19/custom-api-in-azure-mobile-services-client-sdks.aspx

So I was able to save a simple example into a class of all Strings.  However I hit a roadblock when trying to store data into a class with mixed types including an ArrayList.  Here's my class:

```
class clsUser {
    public String UserID;
    public String UserName;
    public String UserStatus;
    public ArrayList<String> UserEmails;
    //Constructors, methods, etc
}
```

An instance of clsUser can have 0 or many UserEmails, so I use an ArrayList.  I should say that I've been using this class in my app - pulling JSON data is new, but I'd like to go this route.

The JsonObject looks like this:

```
{"UserID":85,"UserName":null,"UserEmails":"Call.Me@Maybe.org","UserStatus":"T"}
```

I've also tried adjusting the API so it returns each of these:

```
{"UserID":85,"UserName":null,"UserEmails":"[Call.Me@Maybe.org]","UserStatus":"T"}

{"UserID":85,"UserName":null,"UserEmails":"[{Call.Me@Maybe.org}]","UserStatus":"T"}
```

And I'm getting an error "Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING" which I know means it sees "Call.Me@Maybe.org" as a String, but how can I make it go into the ArrayList field?:

```
07-31 22:59:18.776  27842-27842/com.myapp.app.debug E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.myapp.app.debug, PID: 27842
    com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:176)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:795)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:859)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:832)
            at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.JsonEntityParser.parseResults(JsonEntityParser.java:62)
            at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceClient$4.onCompleted(MobileServiceClient.java:615)
            at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceClient$5.onResponse(MobileServiceClient.java:710)
            at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceClient$6.onPostExecute(MobileServiceClient.java:825)
            at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceClient$6.onPostExecute(MobileServiceClient.java:1)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.JsonTreeReader.expect(JsonTreeReader.java:139)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.JsonTreeReader.beginArray(JsonTreeReader.java:58)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:79)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:93)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:795)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:859)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:832)
            at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.JsonEntityParser.parseResults(JsonEntityParser.java:62)
            at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceClient$4.onCompleted(MobileServiceClient.java:615)
            at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceClient$5.onResponse(MobileServiceClient.java:710)
            at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceClient$6.onPostExecute(MobileServiceClient.java:825)
            at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceClient$6.onPostExecute(MobileServiceClient.java:1)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I think the error is either in the data or the class, but here's the code I'm using for the sake of completeness.  None of the logs get a chance to run before the error comes up:

```
List<Pair<String, String>> params = new ArrayList<Pair<String, String>>();
params.add(new Pair<String, String>("email", emailtext));
params.add(new Pair<String, String>("token", Token));
Azure.invokeApi("user/login", "GET", params, clsUser.class, new ApiOperationCallback<clsUser>() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(clsUser result, Exception e, ServiceFilterResponse response) {
        if (e == null) {
            Log.d("Login GetToken","Azure success: ID=" + result.getUserID());
            Log.d("Login GetToken","Azure success: " + result.getAll().toString());
            currentUser = result;
        } else {
            Log.d("Login GetToken","Azure Error: " + e.toString());
        }
    }
});
```

Anyone have experience with this kind of mixed class?

Comment: I think the Json should be of the form: {"UserID":85,"UserName":null,"UserEmails":["Call.Me@Maybe.org"],"UserStatus":"T"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested this for this situation (since August I've come up with a workaround that I don't feel like revisiting).

However I think the key here is to create a custom deserializer to tell Gson how to interpret the data.

See: [Custom JSON deserializer using Gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16590377/custom-json-deserializer-using-gson)

Then use mClient.registerSerializer method