# How parse this nest json use gson & java? & getvalues

Tags: java, json, gson

I want to retrieve the value that is in the following from Json 'en' 'ja''de'　＆　make a string.xml for the android with the acquired value does it taken out doing what from such nested JSON

```
`{　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　
  "resources": {　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　
    "string": {
      "en": [
        {
          "name": "Parts",
          "character": "wheel"
        },
        {
          "name": "Box",
          "character": "container"
        },
        {
          "name": "ZentraleTeile",
          "character": "engine"
        },
        {
          "name": "Electric",
          "character": "battery"
        },
        {
          "name": "Kabel",
          "character": "flatcable"
        }
      ],
      "ja": [
        {
          "name": "Parts",
          "character": "ホイール"
        },
        {
          "name": "Box",
          "character": "コンテナ"
        },
        {
          "name": "ZentraleTeile",
          "character": "エンジン"
        },
        {
          "name": "Electric",
          "character": "バッテリー"
        },
        {
          "name": "Kabel",
          "character": "フラットケーブル"
        }
      ],
      "zh": [
        {
          "name": "Name",
          "character": "KOM指南2"
        },
        {
          "name": "Parts",
          "character": "轮"
        },
        {
          "name": "Box",
          "character": "集装箱"
        },
        {
          "name": "ZentraleTeile",
          "character": "发动机"
        },
        {
          "name": "Electric",
          "character": "电池"
        },
        {
          "name": "Kabel",
          "character": "扁平电缆"
        }
      ],
      "de": [
        {
        {
          "name": "Parts",
          "character": "Rad"
        },
        {
          "name": "Box",
          "character": "Container"
        },
        {
          "name": "ZentraleTeile",
          "character": "Motor"
        },
        {
          "name": "Electric",
          "character": "Batterie"
        },
        {
          "name": "Kabel",
          "character": "Flachbandkabel"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}`
```

How can I easily do this with GSON and java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use the JsonDeserializer that comes with GSON, to write your custom deserializer just go to the link:

https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Writing-a-Deserializer (present in [Custom JSON deserializer using Gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16590377/custom-json-deserializer-using-gson))

Also check the existing stack overflow response because he has an example using the GsonBuilder, because you need to register the adapter.

Comment: Thank you very much!!
The result that I expected was provided.
I was saved