# JSONObject fields in GSON class - Remains empty

Tags: android, json, serialization, gson, retrofit

Can Gson classes contain fields of type JSONObject? 
Here is my GSON class

```
  class Item {
  @Expose
  var name: String? = ""
  @Expose
  var type: String? = ""
  @Expose
  @SerializedName("agr")
  var aggregate: JSONObject? = null
  @Expose
  @SerializedName("seg")
  var segments: JSONObject? = null
  @Expose
  @SerializedName("ts")
  var timestamp: String? = ""
}
```

The JSONObject fields **segments** and **aggregate** remains an empty JSONObject when serialised (in Retrofit using default GsonConverterFactory). here's what I got. Any suggestions to get it write?

```
{"items":[{"agr":{},"name":"Logged In","seg":{},"ts":"2017-10-17T12:20:32Z","type":"event"}]}
```

Comment: you need a custom deserializer, you can find more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16590377/custom-json-deserializer-using-gson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A work around - Replacing the **JSONObject** with a **HashMap()** had helped me achieve the same results.